# UITable tipo Acordeon IOs Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo la siguiente UITable

```
@IBOutlet weak var resultsTableView: UITableView!

let sectionTitles =  [NSLocalizedString("movementsPayTitle",comment:""), NSLocalizedString("movementsCollectTitle",comment:"")]

     func getCell(cell: QueryPaymentsTableViewCell, resultTransactions: [QueryTransactionModel], row: Int) ->QueryPaymentsTableViewCell
    {
        if (resultTransactions.isEmpty)
        {
            cell.setupDefaultCell()
            return cell
        }
         cell.setCellValues(phone: resultTransactions[row].dst, amount: resultTransactions[row].amount, date: resultTransactions[row].date, reason: resultTransactions[row].reference)
        return cell
    }

    func getNumberOfRows(results: [QueryTransactionModel]) ->Int
    {
        if (results.count == 0)
        {
            return 0
        }
        else
        {
            return results.count
        }
    }

    func heigthHeader(results: [QueryTransactionModel])-> CGFloat{
        if (results.count == 0){
            return 0
        }else{
            return 40
        }
    }

    func showMessageAlert(strTitle: String, strMessage: String, closeModal: Bool){
        if (closeModal){
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.presenter.wfm.showMessageAlert(strTitle: strTitle, strMessage: strMessage)
    }

    func showError(closeModal: Bool){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if (closeModal){
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            self.presenter.showGenericError()
        }
    }
}
extension QueryPaymentsViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if(self.typeSegmentedControl.currentIndex == 0)
        {
            return 2
        }else{
            return 1
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(self.typeSegmentedControl.currentIndex == 0){
            switch (section)
            {
            case 0:
                return getNumberOfRows(results: self.resultPayments)
            case 1:
                return getNumberOfRows(results: self.resultCollections)
            default:
                return 1
            }
        }else{
            return 1
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if(self.typeSegmentedControl.currentIndex == 0){
            switch (section)
            {
            case 0:
                return self.heigthHeader(results: self.resultPayments)
            case 1:
                return self.heigthHeader(results: self.resultCollections)
            default:
                return 0
            }
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let label : UILabel = UILabel()
        label.text = sectionTitles[section]
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 5, width: 200, height: 30)
        label.textColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_2B5034
        view.addSubview(label)
        return view
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if(self.typeSegmentedControl.currentIndex == 0)
            {
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("QueryPaymentsTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! QueryPaymentsTableViewCell
            switch (indexPath.section)
            {
            case 0:
                return getCell(cell: cell, resultTransactions: self.resultPayments, row: indexPath.row)
            case 1:
                return getCell(cell: cell, resultTransactions: self.resultCollections, row: indexPath.row)
            default:
                break
            }
            return cell
        }else{
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("QueryPaymentsBalanceTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! QueryPaymentsBalanceTableViewCell
            cell.setCellValues(
                accType: NSLocalizedString("strLblAccountType",comment:""), accTypeValue: "AHORRO",
                accNumber: NSLocalizedString("strLblAccount",comment:""), accNumberValue: "222xxx4444",
                accName: NSLocalizedString("strLblAccountName",comment:""), accNameValue: "Vicenta Gonzalez",
                availableBalance: NSLocalizedString("strLblAvailableBalance",comment:""), availableBalanceValue: "100",
                totBalance: NSLocalizedString("strLblTotalBalance",comment:""), totBalanceValue: "150")
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
    }
```

lo que me genera algo como esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2 secciones con su listado , lo que me gustaria es que al hacer click sea como un acordeon , osea que solo se vea el header y al clickear de nuevo vuelvan a desplegarse los datos ,desde ya gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo haría sería agregarle un `TapGestureRecognizer` al header de mi tabla. Y 2 propiedades de control si se están mostrando todas las celdas.

Al inicio de la clase:

```
let sectionTitles =  [NSLocalizedString("movementsPayTitle",comment:""), NSLocalizedString("movementsCollectTitle",comment:"")]
fileprivate var pagosHidden = true { didSet {self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet.init(integer: 0), with: .automatic)}}
fileprivate var cobrosHidden = true { didSet {self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet.init(integer: 1), with: .automatic)}}
```

Posterior creamos una función que se ejecutará cuando el usuario seleccione un header.

```
@objc func tapOnHeader(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.view?.tag == 0 {
        pagosHidden = !pagosHidden
    } else if sender.view?.tag == 1 {
        cobrosHidden = !cobrosHidden
    }
}
```

En la función que crea los headers le agregamos el `TapGestureRecognizer` de la siguiente manera

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnHeader(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.tag = section
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    let label : UILabel = UILabel()
    label.tag = section
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    label.text = sectionTitles[section]
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 5, width: 200, height: 30)
    label.textColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_2B5034
    view.addSubview(label)
    return view
}
```

Finalmente le decimos a la tabla que nos regrese 0 celdas o x celdas dependiendo de nuestras propiedades

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(self.typeSegmentedControl.currentIndex == 0){
        switch (section) {
        case 0:
            if pagosHidden { return 0 }
            return getNumberOfRows(results: self.resultPayments)
        case 1:
            if cobrosHidden { return 0 }
            return getNumberOfRows(results: self.resultCollections)
        default:
            return 1
        }
    }else{
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: lo bichare mañana y te cuentoi muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo y dedicacion , gracais por hacer de esta comunidad tan rica